# Need some advices with xpath. It's space

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

i need to extract morpho-synthaxic patterns from an XML file like this :

```
<item number="5">
<titre><article>
<element><data type="type">DET:ART</data><data type="lemma">le</data><data type="string">Les</data></element>
<element><data type="type">NOM</data><data type="lemma">temps</data><data type="string">temps</data></element>
<element><data type="type">ADJ</data><data type="lemma">fort</data><data type="string">forts</data></element>
<element><data type="type">VER:pper</data><data type="lemma">attendre</data><data type="string">attendus</data></element>
<element><data type="type">PRP</data><data type="lemma">de</data><data type="string">de</data></element>
<element><data type="type">DET:POS</data><data type="lemma">@ord@</data><data type="string">2017.</data></element>
</article>
```

I choose to extract the DET-NOUN-ADJ pattern. I have the correct xpath :

```
   <xsl:for-each select="//data[contains(.,'DET')][@type='type']/../following-sibling::*[1][data[@type='type']/text()='NOM']/following-sibling::*[1][data[@type='type']/text()='ADJ']">
        <xsl:variable name="adj" select="preceding-sibling::*[2][@type='string']/text()"/>
        <xsl:variable name="nom" select="preceding-sibling::*[1]/data[@type='string']/text()"/>
        <xsl:variable name="det" select="//data[contains(.,'DET')][@type='string']/text()"/>
        <xsl:value-of select="concat($det, ' ', $nom, ' ', $adj)"/>
        <xsl:text>
        </xsl:text>
    </xsl:for-each>
```

But i can't extract them from the xpath request in foreach loop. Do you have any advice ? I need to build the pattern with value of @type='string'.

I want the following output : text, one line by pattern

```
DET NOM ADJ
le garcon gentil
du pain délicieux
une fille jolie
des chaussures bleues
```

Comment: Please post a [mcve], not snippets taken out of context. Also include the exact result (as code) you expect to get.

Comment: I want all strings printed from a pattern DET-NOM-ADJ. In french, i want a list like that :
`code`
les enfants méchants
du bondin noir
des filles charmantes
`code`
One line for each pattern (3 words here)

Comment: Please edit your question and add the **exact result (as code)** you expect to get.

Comment: okay sir. I would like this following output : textfile, one line by pattern. A pattern is a DET-NOM-ADJ following each other. The goal is to get it, and print the formes (string) of words from pattern
Exemple<br/>
les enfants méchants<br/>   
du bondin noir<br/>  
des filles charmantes<br/>  
etc...<br/>

Comment: You are not reading my comments carefully enough - even after I have added bold styling to the most important part.

Comment: Your output does not match the input. And the input is still not well-formed XML. I have posted an answer that uses my own example. You will need to adjust this to your actual needs.

Answer (score 1):

Do you meen something like this?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet 
  version="1.0" 
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
  >
  
  <xsl:template match="article">
    <br/>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="element[data[@type='type' and text()='DET:ART']]"/>
    <xsl:text> </xsl:text>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="element[data[@type='type' and text()='NOM']]"/>
    <xsl:text> </xsl:text>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="element[data[@type='type' and text()='ADJ']]"/>
  </xsl:template>
  
  <xsl:template match="element">
    <xsl:value-of select="data[@type='string']"/>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Yes ! but my tokens need to be in the right order and following each other DET-NOM-ADJ

Comment: They are in the right order. Probably you need to expand your example and show the wanted outcome

Comment: My book nice  (DET-NOM-ADJ) I need to extract all these patterns from an xml file

Answer (score 1):

Consider the following example:

**XML**

```
<articles>
    <article>
        <element>
            <data type="type">DET:ART</data>
            <data type="lemma">le</data>
            <data type="string">Les</data>
        </element>
        <element>
            <data type="type">NOM</data>
            <data type="lemma">temps</data>
            <data type="string">temps</data>
        </element>
        <element>
            <data type="type">ADJ</data>
            <data type="lemma">fort</data>
            <data type="string">forts</data>
        </element>
        <element>
            <data type="type">VER:pper</data>
            <data type="lemma">attendre</data>
            <data type="string">attendus</data>
        </element>
        <element>
            <data type="type">PRP</data>
            <data type="lemma">de</data>
            <data type="string">de</data>
        </element>
        <element>
            <data type="type">DET:POS</data>
            <data type="lemma">@ord@</data>
            <data type="string">2017.</data>
        </element>
    </article>
    <article>
        <element>
            <data type="type">DET:ART</data>
            <data type="lemma">une </data>
            <data type="string">Une</data>
        </element>
        <element>
            <data type="type">NOM</data>
            <data type="lemma">fille</data>
            <data type="string">fille</data>
        </element>
        <element>
            <data type="type">ADJ</data>
            <data type="lemma">jolie</data>
            <data type="string">jolie</data>
        </element>
        <element>
            <data type="type">VER:pper</data>
            <data type="lemma">xyz</data>
            <data type="string">abc</data>
        </element>
        <element>
            <data type="type">PRP</data>
            <data type="lemma">zz</data>
            <data type="string">yy</data>
        </element>
        <element>
            <data type="type">DET:POS</data>
            <data type="lemma">@ttt@</data>
            <data type="string">2018.</data>
        </element>
    </article>
</articles>
```

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="text" encoding="UTF-8"/>

<xsl:template match="/articles">
    <!-- header -->
    <xsl:text>DET,NOM,ADJ&#10;</xsl:text>
    <!-- data -->
    <xsl:for-each select="article">
        <xsl:value-of select="element[contains(data[@type='type'],'DET')]/data[@type='string']"/>
        <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="element[data[@type='type']='NOM']/data[@type='string']"/>
        <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="element[data[@type='type']='ADJ']/data[@type='string']"/>
        <xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Result**

```
DET,NOM,ADJ
Les,temps,forts
Une,fille,jolie
```

Comment: Thx for your code but the DET still to be modify. It need to include contains(text(), 'DET') because DET is always with ART or other. And i can't do that with Xpath.

Comment: Yes, you can. It's a rather trivial adjustment - see my edited answer.

Comment: The words have to strictly follow each other with no other word than the sequence DET-NOM-ADJ michael